# Materialize input field labels merging

Tags: materialize, input-field

I have as part of a form this contact information section:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col s12">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
    <input id="nameico" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="nameico">Contact Name</label>
</div>
<div class="col s12">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
    <input id="emailico" type="email" class="validate">
    <label for="emailico">Contact Email</label>
</div>
<div class="col s12">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
    <input id="telico" type="tel" class="validate">
    <label for="telico">Contact Phone</label>
</div>
</div>
```

However all three label are overlapping each other all inside the first input field for the persons name.

[image: Input labels overlapping]

Comment: Are you using any other third party css package aside from materializecss?

Comment: Did you try to call `Materialize.updateTextFields();` ?

Comment: Now Materialize CSS is updated, so now you can use M.updateTextFields();

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Code may be it can help you.

JSFiddle link - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5y147f6f/1/)

HTML Code -

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col s12 input-field">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
    <input id="nameico" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="nameico">Contact Name</label>
</div>
<div class="col s12 input-field">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
    <input id="emailico" type="email" class="validate">
    <label for="emailico">Contact Email</label>
</div>
<div class="col s12 input-field">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
    <input id="telico" type="tel" class="validate">
    <label for="telico">Contact Phone</label>
</div>
</div>
```